# Vue.js weird rendering with class binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So basically I have an html table with a `v-for` that loops over an array of objects, nothing complicated here. When the user clicks on a row, it toggles the `selected` property of the object "linked" to the given row.

Now, I also setup a simple class-binding with `v-bind:class="{'active': n.selected}"` where `n` is my object, but it doesnt update. Now what is more weird is that I use the webpack template from the vue-cli, and when I :

- Select a bunch of rows (no active class binded)
- update code
- hit `F5` which triggers the webpack hot-reload

The selected rows suddenly get the `active` class, as the CSS says so, until the webpack hot-reload has regenerated the page.
Here is my code :

```
<tr
    v-for="n in node.children"
    track-by="id"
    v-on:click="toggleElement(n)"
    v-bind:class="{'active': n.selected}">
<td>
    <i class="icons">
        <i class="folder yellow icon"></i>
    </i>
</td>
<td><a v-on:click.stop="getLevel(n.id)">{{ n.name }}</a></td>
<td><span v-if="n.modification_date">{{ n.modification_date | moment "calendar"}}</span><span v-else>-</span></td>
<td><span v-if="n.size">{{ n.size }}</span><span v-else>-</span></td>
```

And for the javascript method

```
toggleElement: function(element) {
            element.selected =  !!(element.selected === undefined || !element.selected);
        },
```

Now some more details, the objects are being retrieved by an ajax call, and the `selected` property doesnt exist from the start.

Any advice or solution ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **by default**,vue.js can not track the property you add after vue instance had been created
- **BUT**,there is some method you can call to tell vue that new properties been added:

  > vm.$set('selected', true) //this will make "selected" propertie
  >   trackable

Answer (score 1):

First, do not forget to add the closing `</tr>` in your code.

Second, you can not add new attributes on objects after creating them with VueJS.

If when creating the element, its attribute `selected` was undefined, then VueJS will not add the getter/setter on it and changing it won't update the interface.

You will need to add the `selected` attribute before passing it to VueJS.